# Capturing Failed Requests on Heroku (The percentage of failed requests has exceeded your threshold..)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My Rails app hosted on Heroku is experiencing a spike of failed requests and I can't figure out why. In particular, I'm receiving many emails saying:

> The percentage of failed requests for [app] has exceeded your threshold setting of 5.0%

Moreover, I can't seem to connect the time I'm receiving these emails from Heroku with any system errors in my Heroku monitoring tools. For example, I received an email at 10:47 p.m. yesterday that the failed requests had exceeded 5%, but in Heroku there's no corresponding error (indicated where it should be on the graph below).
[image]

Afterward receiving the email described above, I'll receive an email a few minutes later indicating that the failed requests is back below the threshold. This has now started happening 1-2 times per day.

I need to capture these failed requests so that I can diagnose and fix what's happening. I'm open to any form of solution, even paying for a product, but these errors are so rare that trailing my logs isn't a feasible solution.

Thanks in advance. Any advice is appreciated!